# Can a polynomial form any one to one and continuous graph?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, continuity

Hello I was wondering if it was possible to right any one to one and continuous graph as a polynomial with real co-efficient s. If this is not so why? It seems like it would possible to just write a piecewise function that would make it impossible for it to be represented by a polynomial but I am curious on to why that is mathematically. Or in other words what characteristics do polynomials contain that allow or don't allow them to represent such a graph.

Comment: $e^x$ is not a polynomial (it goes to $0$ at $-\infty$).

Comment: Polynomials are smooth (the derivatives up to any order exist). For example $|x|$ is not smooth at $x=0$ and it can not thus be represented as a polynomial.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä Oh ok so are you saying that since at every point of a polynomial there exists a derivative that it cannot represent functions where a derivative does not exist?

Comment: Yes. If you write the same thing in two ways, they should *really* be the same: If $f=g$, then $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at the same points (you can just replace $f$ with $g$ everywhere in the definition, since they are supposed to be the same).